# How to add line with spaces at beginning, and with backslash at end with sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I know the sed syntax to add a line after another line in a file, which is

```
sed -i '/LINE1/a LINE2' FILE
```

This adds LINE2 after LINE1 in FILE correct? How do I add a line with a backslash at the end? For example, from

```
This is a a line \
    Indented line1 \
    Indented line2 \
    Line3
```

To

```
This is a a line \
    Indented line1 \
    Indented line2 \
    Added line \
    Line3
```

Answer (score 6):

Just put the backslash in and escape it:

```
sed -i '/line2/a Added line \\' FILE
```

If you want the four-space indent, then:

```
sed -i '/line2/a \    Added line \\' FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk, sed is best for simple substitutions on a single line not for anything involving multiple lines or anything else remotely complicated:

```
$ awk '{print} /line2/{ print substr($0,1,match($0,/[^[:space:]]/)-1) "Added line \\" }' file
This is a a line \
    Indented line1 \
    Indented line2 \
    Added line \
    Line3
```

The above will line up your added line with the indenting of the preceding one no matter what your leading white space is because it simply replaces anything after the white space with your replacement text.

Comment: I am trying your solution but it seems not to work : here the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556152/sed-insert-line-after-match-with-a-double-tab-for-the-beginning-of-inserted-li , if you could see what's wrong, regards

Comment: [My answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44556217/1745001) specifically shows you how to do exactly what you want and why are you commenting under this answer instead of that one??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the insert command:

```
sed '/\\$/!i \    Added line \\' file
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
awk 'NR==3{$0=$0 "\n\tAdded Line \\"}7' file
```