# sed - insert line after match with a double tab for the beginning of inserted line

Tags: awk, sed

I have the following input.txt :

```
        "loop:\n\t" 
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
```

and I want to insert a line between first and second line in order to get :

```
    "loop:\n\t" 
    "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t" 
    "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
```

Here what I tried :

```
sed '/loop\:/a "\t \t add %%g1, 1, %%g1\\n\\t"' input.txt
```

But with this, I get :

```
        "loop:\n\t" 
"       add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t" 
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
```

As you can see, first quote of inserted line is at the beginning of line and not juste before `add` word.

How to circumvent this issue ?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1 :**

I realized that spaces between the begin of each line and the first characters are not tabulations but classical spaces.

Then, I tried to use this solution (from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790530/how-to-add-line-with-spaces-at-beginning-and-with-backslash-at-end-with-sed))

```
awk '{print} /loop\:/{ print substr($0,1,match($0,/[^[:space:]]/)-1) "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"}' input.txt
```

It seems this command line computes the right indentation from previous line but unfortunately, I get with this :

```
           "loop:\n\t" 
"add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t" 
           "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
```

whereas I would like to have :

```
           "loop:\n\t" 
           "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t" 
           "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
```

Could you see the error ?

Regards

Comment: If that awk script produces that output then your awk is severely broken in very specific and magical ways (which I highly doubt). `print ... "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"` simply **cannot** output `"add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"` as the string you're passing to `print` doesn't contain double quotes and it doesn't escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything even slightly more interesting just use awk instead for clarity, portability, efficiency and most other desirable attributes of software:

```
$ awk '{print} /loop:/{print "\t\"add %%g1, 1, %%g1\\n\\t\""}' file
        "loop:\n\t"
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
```

The above just implements what you were trying to do with sed but there's probably a better approach depending on your real requirements, e.g. any of these has benefits over the above but produce the same output under different conditions:

```
$ awk '1;NR==2' file
        "loop:\n\t"
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"


$ awk '{print} f{print;f=0} /loop:/{f=1}' file
        "loop:\n\t"
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"

$ awk '{print} /loop:/{sub(/".*/,""); print $0 "\"add %%g1, 1, %%g1\\n\\t\""}' file
        "loop:\n\t"
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
        "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\n\t"
```

Based on the comment you left under [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25793684/1745001) it sounds like you do want one of those bottom so you don't have to specify the indentation.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you give me please some details about the command that I have used : **awk '{print} /loop:/{sub(/".*/,""); print $0 "\"add %%g1, 1, %%g1\\n\\t\""}' ** . Do you replace the block "loop:" by "loop:" + "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\\n\\t\"" ??

Comment: You're welcome. `sub(/".*/,"")` removes everything after the first `"` on the `loop:` line (so just leaving the leading white space indentation) then `print $0 "..."` prints that white space followed by the new string.

Comment: Just one last question : in this command, how do you insert the new line "add %%g1 .... ", I mean, where is the carriage return after loop line ? thanks

Comment: The loop line was already printed by the `{print}` lust like every other existing line is printed by that statement, now we're operating on just the loop line again (`/loop:/`) to strip from the " on and add the new string before printing again.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

Escape first `\t` with a backslash:

```
sed '/loop\:/a \\t "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\\n\\t"' file
```

or a search and replace:

```
sed 's/loop\:.*/&\n\t "add %%g1, 1, %%g1\\n\\t"/' file
```